# Qt multimedia mediaplayer audiorole

Tags: qt, audio, qml

I a would like to use Qtmultimedia for audio output, but  need something really precise. In the mediaPlayer class, there is the audioRole property. For the purpose of being really (I mean really really  REALLY) precise, which one should I choose and why?
here is [the link](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qml-qtmultimedia-mediaplayer.html)
Thanks

Comment: The documentation is very clear, what is your doubt? 
you could use MusicRole, have you tried to try any?

Comment: The documentation tells you which role does what. The role I want is not listed. The roles functions are not listed. What I mean is that it does not say which roles tchnically does what. I sure can guess that game sounds need to be on time, but is this the best option. I need something really really on time.

Comment: Given that each of the enumerated roles corresponds exactly to specific audio type, what makes things ambiguous?

Comment: @MarcheRemi What role do you want?

Comment: @MarcheRemi 
Not all the roles will be available in an OS, or version of OS, since these depend on the backend that Qt uses for that OS.

Comment: Okay let's put the thing clear. I wanna do a metronome. Each beat needs to be perfectly on time

Comment: @MarcheRemi As every library provides: *there is what there is*. Qt Multimedia is made for video playback and commercial music, and I do not know if your application is within that range.

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks. I will have to test all the audioRoles in that case.

Comment: @MarcheRemi 
Exactly, a simple for loop will be useful for your test. :D